# Android Splash screen duration

Tags: android, timer, splash-screen

We are using the splash screen to show the company logo every time user open the app. Currently, we are showing the splash screen for 3 Seconds.

Below is the code:

```
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;      // Delay of 3 Seconds

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, AnotheActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

But this splash screen duration is just randomly chosen within team.
We kind-of know that Splash screen in general is not all that encouraged in Android app ecosystem, but since this is our app's need, hence it is implemented.

**My Question**: Is there any standard Android guideline/best practice for choosing the RIGHT splash screen duration time?

Comment: If you don't do anything in those 3 seconds, why even show it? *this is our app's need,* what is the need?

Comment: *Is there any standard Android guideline/best practice for choosing the RIGHT splash screen duration time*. As you said, It is not encouraged, why do you expect best practises for something *not encouraged*

Comment: @Blackbelt Since its such common idioms in Android, hence! But its ok, if there is no such benchmark.

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Agree. App don't do anything during that time. We may choose to remove this in future.

Comment: the way I see it, it is a product related decision and the product people should decide it

Comment: @Blackbelt Sometimes, it's a **need**. I.e.: loading all the graphics or create a database before the app starts.

Comment: @Blackbelt The other places such as App bar(ActionBar) is too much cluttered currently, hence we are unable to showcase branding, Hence using splash screen as a last measure

Comment: I solved that issue by putting the loadings into an Asynctask inside the Splash Screen. Then, in `onPostExecute()`, I finish the Splash Screen Activity and load the default one (Main Activity) - no arbitrary timings. I also show an indeterminate ProgressBar, just to let the user understand that there's a little delay and a writing which says "Wait while loading...". The UI for the Splash Screen is really the About Screen (which in turn, uses the same background of the Main Activity)  plus these two elements added. So, you get the feeling of something coherent.

Comment: Best use countdown timer method to hold the splash screen

Comment: @AADTechnical there are varied opinions here, but I honestly don't think there is anything wrong with splash screens. We use it widely for our clientele (for branding purposes) and standard duration we use is 2.5s (2500ms) and it has worked out well for us. It is important to note that we perform some startup background work during this time, which usually takes about a second. Also, unrelated but make sure you call `yourHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to ensure the following activity isn't launched if the user exits the app while on the splash screen

Comment: @Abhijit You are right. There are varied opinions. And my intention was to understand if any common best practice out there in developer community for splash screen. Anyway most developer seems to be agreed that there are other alternatives exist for the splash and we may choose an alternative in coming builds

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better option is to use a splash screen activity with a custom theme, that starts the main content activity. With this there is no need to use a timer, as it switches to main content when the app is ready, and in the meantime shows a picture that is inside the theme.

Here is tutorial how to do it - https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Main parts from the tutorial:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> THEME HERE!!!
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>

</style>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/black"/>

    <item>

        <bitmap

            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_image"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

It is even possible to add the style to the application, without a need to use a separate activity.

Comment: as I can see, there is no std. it seems for what should be the duration for splash screen. hence we may use an alternative to splash and I guess your solution looks appropriate for that fit.

Comment: @MikelisKaneps this is one of the best solution ever. This is the best method to create splash screen. It reduces app open time and shows activity immediately. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Splash screen it's bad practice, when it possible not to use it than please avoid using splash screen. You can read a some articles about this [link1](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/), [link2](https://plus.google.com/+ColtMcAnlis/posts/4VUCWXXbZUy).

But if need to show splash than use through creating a custom theme that overrides `android:windowBackground`, then replacing that custom theme with your standard theme before calling `super.onCreate()`. Here is [tutorial](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd) of implementation and detailed description.

Assuming you have a theme called AppTheme, your launcher theme would be:

`<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>`

Then apply your theme to your activity in your AndroidManifest.xml using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher".`

The easiest way to transition back to your normal theme is to call setTheme(R.style.AppTheme) before super.onCreate() and setContentView():

`public class MyMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Make sure this is before calling super.onCreate
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MyApp);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
  }
}`

Comment: Sometimes, it's a **need**. I.e.: loading all the graphics or create a database before the app starts.

Comment: If used unnecessarily, it might be bad but in some cases it is needed, moreover it can be used to strengthen your brand, obviously if used the right way !!

Comment: But what **if it is necessary**, which is the case of most **conscious developers**?

Comment: Sure, I understand this, and I wrote how to use it in better way when you need it

Answer (score 1):

Google guidelines are pretty clear.
Use splash screen only if you must. (If you don't have anything to show to user) It should be visible only until you have some data to show.
If you go trough Google apps you will very rear see a splashscreen.
There is much cleverer ways to brand your app.
You can find more data [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/).

Comment: `... only if you must` Which is why we do, mostly. I.e.: loading the graphics or create a database **before** the app starts.

Comment: Than show it just until everything is loaded. Don't show it for fixed amount of time.

Comment: ... which is what the OP actually asked for.

Answer (score 0):

A community-accepted standard solution is using a launch theme.

Check out this post: http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts